# List(of String()) contains String()

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find out if an array of Strings exists in a list of arrays of Strings, but am running into some confusion. Here is some code:

```
Dim listResults as List(of String)
Dim listStringArrays as List(of String())
Dim Something as String() = {"Foo", "Bar", "Stuff"}
Dim Otherthing as string() = {"Foo", "Bar", "Stuff"}

listStringArrays.Add(Something)

IF listStringArrays.Contains(Otherthing) then
listResults.Add("True")
Else
listResults.Add("False")
End If

IF listStringArrays(0).Equals(Otherthing) then
listResults.Add("True")
Else
listResults.Add("False")
End If
```

listResults would then contain two "False". But strangely:

```
Something(0) = Otherthing(0)
Something(1) = Otherthing(1)
Something(2) = Otherthing(2)
```

These would all evaluate to true. How can I find out if my listStringArrays contains Otherthing if Contains does not work?

Bonus question: Why would Contains not work in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two arrays with the same contents are still not the same array. `Something = Otherthing` is false. That's why `Contains` doesn't work.

You could instead use [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567.aspx) to see whether any of the arrays in `listStringArrays` have the same contents as `Otherthing`.

```
If listStringArrays.Any(Function(t) t.SequenceEqual(Otherthing)) Then
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't two arrays with the same contents be equal? Would not two string variables set to the same sequence of characters be equal?

Comment: String is a bit special. The String class overrides `Equals` and the `=` equality operator so it works like you say. In general though, for reference types (like array and string), `=` will check whether the objects are the same object, rather than different but "equal" objects.

Comment: It's a matter of value equality and reference equality.  By default, value types, i.e. structures, use value equality, i.e. whether two objects have the same contents, while reference types, i.e. classes, use reference equality, i.e. whether two references refer to the same object.  Let's say you and I each write a shopping list of bread, milk and potatoes.  Our lists both have the same contents but would you call them the same list? No, you wouldn't, and so it is with your code. Strings are a special case, i.e. a reference type that defaults to value equality, for convenience.